# Automated Export to CSV Using SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I have created a view, which pulls in columns from several tables. I need to export this view into a CSV file on a weekly basis, and so I would like to set up some sort of automated process for this. I have read many examples of how I can do a simple right click and "Save Results As", or using the export wizard, but I do not know how I can automate this process to run weekly.

I am somewhat of a newbie with all things microsoft, so any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I found this somewhat easier to accomplish with Powershell.  I would post the steps, but your question specifies Management Studio in the ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to schedule a job to run every week. Please have a look at here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It is also easy to setup a mailer that would mail a csv file as an attachment on a weekly basis using `sp_send_dbmail` command.

**As a CSV attachment:**

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'AdventureWorks2008R2 Administrator',
    @recipients = 'danw@Adventure-Works.com',
    @query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Production.WorkOrder
                  WHERE DueDate > ''2006-04-30''
                  AND  DATEDIFF(dd, ''2006-04-30'', DueDate) < 2' ,
    @subject = 'Work Order Count',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1 ;
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

Comment: Note that Microsoft SQL will include a BOM at the start of the file, which prevents Excel from recognizing the file format.  Damn you Microsoft for making your files in-compatible!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an SSIS package (just google "sql server export data ssis") and execute it each week (you can create an automated task for this) or you can use xp's like demonstrated [in this article.](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/)

Comment: Thanks for this, the article helped a lot.